# What is this mold/fungus?

Tags: identification, fungus, mold

[image]

Is it harmful? What should I do about it?

It was undoubtedly caused by the excess water on the surface from the drippers. Those are now off.

Comment: The appearance is similar but different than that one.

Comment: There are millions of species of fungi. If they are growing on soil they have a similar lifestyle regardless of appearance and are not a problem to your plants.

Comment: I'd use a DECOMPOSED organic mulch, wood chunks do little for combating weeds.  Decomposed organic mulch feeds your other soil organisms that are necessary for healthy soil and healthy plants.  Otherwise, try to allow the soil to dry out a bit before the next watering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a problem, will go away as the soil dries out.

The fungus is having a meal of the woody organic matter in the soil.

No action is required on your part.